# RAILS Mongoid finding document by id

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-7

When I do in rails console:

```
User.first
 => #<User _id: 6241f97de64d1eb2cc003d08,....
```

I get document, but when I try to find it by id like

User.find('6241f97de64d1eb2cc003d08') or User.find(BSON::ObjectId('6241f97de64d1eb2cc003d08')) or
User.find('6241f97de64d1eb2cc003d08'.to_bson) etc

I get:

```
message:                                                                          
  Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 6241f97de64d1eb2cc003d08.
```

also

```
3.0.3 :049 > User.where(_id: BSON::ObjectId('6241f97de64d1eb2cc003d08')).find
 => nil
```

Why it does not work????

I use rails 7 and mongoid

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution.

User model was defined like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :_id, type: String
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
end
```

And changing it to this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  # field :_id, type: String
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
end
```

Commenting "field: _id" did the trick. I think string type was "covering" expected ObjectId as _id and find methods are converting strings into ObjectId so we ended up in search against string vs ObjectId.